# Is "to have to do something with" ambiguous?

Tags: meaning, verbs, ambiguity

I am struggling with understanding of this structure. So here is something I would need to explain:

> It has to do something with the car. [It is related to the car somehow.]

But what if I want to say that (hypothetically) "it" (e.g. a monster) must perform an action with/on the car, wouldn't it look the same?

> It has to do something with the car. [It must perform an action with the car.]

Or:

> He has to do something with the fraud. [He is involved in the fraud.]
>
> He has to do something with his friend. [I want to express that he must do something together with his friend.]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have put the words the wrong way around in your first example:

> It **has something to do with** the car

This means *it* involves the car in some way. For example

> My back pain has something to do with how I sit.

This means that the pain in my back is somehow related to how I sit.

*Has something to do with* is an idiom that means *is related to* or *involves*. The word *something* must come before the verb *to do* for it to mean this.

The other way around means, as you say, that *it* (whatever *it* is) must do something with the car. For example:

> I need to do something with all the junk in my flat.

This means that the junk in my flat needs something doing to it by me.

---

As an aside, two related idioms are

- *Has nothing to do with*, which means *is unrelated to* or *does not involve*
  e.g. "Having hair on my chest **has nothing to do with** eating the crust of my sandwiches".
- *Has everything to do with*, which is an emphatic form of *has something to do with*, sometimes used literally to mean *only related to* or *only involves*.

In fact there are many possible phrases of the form *has X to do with ...* . *X* can be, I think, any adverb that implies quantity. E.g.

- It has *little* to do with the car
- It has *most* to do with the car
- It has *all* to do with the car

The adverb used changes how related *it* is to, e.g. *the car*.